# ReactiveMongo: Should I disconnect?

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, disconnect, reactivemongo

Do I have to close some instances after the completion of work with the base using the `ReactiveMongo` driver?

When I do a lot of inserts and then I call `driver.close()`, many operations can not be completed with `dead letters` akka messages.

Can I be sure that he will complete all operations before shutting down without await all operations futures?

Comment: Are you sure the messages you see ending up in the dead letters are due to failing operations? They may be acks or things like that.

Comment: @vptheron, I see it in the logs, data insertion operations started shortly before closing the driver, they are no changes in the database

Comment: You should not close the driver after DB operation. It would close the underlying actor system and cause issues.

Comment: If you are using the ask pattern you can compose a sequence of Futures with Future.sequence and then onComplete of the big future of all operations close the connection

Comment: @AndrewCassidy and if I work with ReactiveMongo from many different methods? I use it in MapReduce Hadoop job.